# Audio amplifier

Tags: audio

I would like to use a [cubox-i](http://solid-run.com/product/cubox-i4x4/) (or any arm based single-board computer) as controler for a media installation.

I have a jvc audio amplifier which have an heavy power consumption, and no possibilities to manage that remotly, for example with hdmi-cec. I have also 5.1 speakers.

I would like to find an audio amplifier manageable by hdmi-cec, cubox have only a s/pdif output, so the audio amplifier should have one too.

Or ideally some electronic cards or adapters able to transmit the sound from the s/pdif to my speakers with that kind of cable:

[image]

By the way, could you tell me the name of these cables?

Comment: They're just speaker cables.

Comment: can I plug these cables in that: http://www.amazon.com/Generic-Digital-Optical-5-1-Channel-Decoder/dp/B00DEV67TA/ref=sr_1_12?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1410108121&sr=1-12&keywords=optical+5.1+dac ?

Comment: http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/the-best-speaker-cable/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_wire And no, that device seems to have co-axial connectors. If your speakers use that style of cable, chances are they are passive, and need a powered amp for it.